# Prove $f$ and $g$ are bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> If $f+g$ and $f-g$ are bounded, prove that $f$ and $g$ are bounded.

All I know that a function is bounded if there exists a $M$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M $

Do I do $|f+g|\leq M$ and $|f-g|\leq N$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write
$$ f=\frac{f+g}{2}+\frac{f-g}{2}$$
and
$$ g=\frac{f+g}{2}-\frac{f-g}{2} $$
and use the bounds for $f+g$ and $f-g$ along with the triangle inequality.

Comment: if you dont mind can you tell me where u got those equations from?

Comment: It's a fairly common trick, though maybe a bit hard to come up with if you haven't seen it before.

Comment: If say $|f+g|\leq M$ and $|f-g|\leq N$, you can use the identities in my answer and the triangle inequality to get bounds on $f$ and $g$.

Comment: oh k thanks, ill try that

Comment: It's enough to do $|f+g|\leq M$, for instance. After all, absolute values are always $\geq 0$.

Comment: Using the first one, we have $|f|=\frac{1}{2}|(f+g)+(f-g)|\leq \frac{1}{2}|f+g|+\frac{1}{2}|f-g|\leq \frac{M+N}{2}$, and similarly for $g$.

Comment: for g it would be (M-N)/2 right

Comment: No, it would still be $\frac{M+N}{2}$ because the triangle inequality yields $|(f+g)-(f-g)|\leq |f+g|+|f-g|$.